# How to identify if an ` <a>` has been visited or not in jquery

Tags: jquery

Want to know , How to identify if an `<a>` has been visited or not in jquery.
i.e.

```
if(`<a> has been visited`)
{
   //execute this code
}
else
{
   //execute that code
}
```

Comment: I think he means if it has been clicked in the past ;)

Comment: This is not what i want.I know we have click() in jquery

Comment: @douwe @Wondering, see my comment at middus' answer.

Comment: As I noted in another comment - the ability for a page to make the determination of whether an arbitrary link has been visited is considered to be a security bug by browser maintainers. Any good way to do this is likely to be exploited and eventually patched.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>For executing code on click on a link, you may use:</strike>

```
$('a').click(function() {

   // execute this code

});
```

For executing code at a certain time for checking all links:

```
// adding event handler on page load
$('a').click(function() {

   // save that it has been clicked on this link
   $(this).attr('hasBeenClicked', 'true');

});

// execude this on demand
$('a').each(function() {

   if($(this).attr('hasBeenClicked') == 'true')
   {
          // execute code
   }
   else
   {
          // execute code
   }

});
```

Comment: have a look at the second section... is that what you want?

Comment: Upvote for second part, that's probably exactly what he wants.

Comment: Not valid solution imo. What if he visited google.com from outside your page, then arrives to your page, from which he hasn't visited google.com...

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you want to detect links (on the page) that user visited previously (either from this or from any other page), right?

I believe there is no 100% way but this hack might help. It goes like this: First you set up your CSS so that there is a distinction between `a:link` and `a:visited` which you later use to measure for each link.

For example, you can set-up CSS like this:

```
a, a:link { margin: 0 }
a:visited { margin-bottom: 1px }
```

Then if your html is this (clearly stackoverflow.com is visited, and other garbage link is not):

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow.com</a><br>
<a href="http://fjhgsfljhgsljf">some unvisited link</a>​
```

You measure them with this script:

```
​$('a').each(function () {
    var isClicked = !!parseInt($(this).css('margin-bottom'));
    alert('Is ' + $(this).text() + ' visited: ' + isClicked);
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

(`!!parseInt('1px')` yields `true` and `!!parseInt('0px')` yields `false`)

I chose `margin-bottom` measurable as it makes no visual distinction in my case. You may chose something else.

Comment: !!parseInt(...) makes me shiver. how about if($(this).css('margin-bottom') === '1px'

Comment: @Andreas: No problem, as it is an implementation detail. I'm just illustrating general idea (in somewhat dirty way **:)**).

Comment: This is the only answer that seems to get the point of the original question. The ability for a page to make this determination is considered a security risk by browser maintainers, as it allows a page to determine that you've been to particular home banking sites, etc. Thus, any "good" solution that seems to work reliably is probably one that will stop working in a browser security update someday.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to check somewhere in the code if the link has been clicked at any given time, just use a variable.

```
var aClicked = false;
$('identifier to the a').click(function() {aClicked = true});
```

At the point you want to do the check:

```
if( aClicked ) {
}
```

Comment: What would be wrong with my answer? He is clearly not looking for the click event ;)

Comment: not what he's asking for but the answer isn't any more wrong than all the other wrong ones :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event?

Comment: No.say we have hasClass() to identify if class ispresent, likewise do we have any for click?

Comment: @Wondering: there is not. You can however simulate this by just using addClass/hasClass to your anchors. (or by using attributes)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    if( !$(this).data('clicked') ) {
       $(this).data('clicked', 1);
       something();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

OK....let's do this simple by using class attributes.

In jQuery

```
$('a').click(function() {
   if (!$(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
     $(this).addClass("clicked");
   }
   //You can toggle by doing this 
   //else  {
   //  $(this).removeClass("clicked");
   //}

   if ($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
     //Do Stuff....
   }
});
```

that way, you can iterate through `<a>` and check if `$(this).hasClass("clicked"))` like this:

```
$('a').each(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
     //Do Stuff....
   }
});
```